# Python - Decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to learn [Decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) . 
I understood the concept of it and now trying to implement it.

**Here is the code that I've written**
The code is self-explanatory. It just checks whether the argument passed in `int` or not.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner():
        if issubclass(x,int): pass
        else: return 'invalid values'

    return inner()

@wrapper
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

print add('a',2)
```

It's throwing error saying `global name 'x' is not defined`. I understand that it is not defined under `inner`, but didnt know how to rectify this code? Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your decorator should look like this:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(x, y): # inner function needs parameters
        if issubclass(type(x), int): # maybe you looked for isinstance?
            return func(x, y) # call the wrapped function
        else: 
            return 'invalid values'
    return inner # return the inner function (don't call it)
```

Some points to note:

- `issubclass` expects a class as first argument (you could replace it with a simple try/except TypeError).
- the wrapper should return a function, not the result of a called function
- you should actually call the wrapped function in the inner function
- your inner function didn't have parameters

You can find a good explanation of decorators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/142637).

Comment: I'd use `type(x)` instead of `x.__class__`, if not using `isinstance()`.

Comment: Thanks for rectifying the code. I've doubt in the concept of wrapper function. Is it actually necessary to write a nested function to check  whether the values are int or not. I mean can't it be done without using a nested function. For eg:- `def wrapper(x,y): if issubclass(x.__class__, int): return func(x, y) else: return 'invalid values' `

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the comment; using `type(x)` is better than `x.__class__`. Fixed it.

Comment: @python-coder No, that will not work. When you use `wrapper` as a decorator, it will be called with the wrapped function as first argument.

Comment: To be more upwards-compatible, you could use a flexible list of arguments:  `def inner(x, *args, **kwargs):` and `return func(x, *args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 3):

There are three issues I see with your current code.

First, you're calling the `inner` function, rather than returning a reference to it.

Second, your `inner` function doesn't take the same arguments as the function you're decorating. In this case, you need to take at least the `x` argument explicitly (some inner functions can use `*args` and `**kwargs` exclusively, but aparently not yours).

Lastly, you're never calling the wrapped function. While this isn't strictly required (it might be useful to swap out a method with a decorator during development), usually you want to call the function at some point during the inner function's code.

So, to wrap the whole thing together, I think you want your code to be something like this:

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(x, y):
        if issubclass(x, int): # issue 2
            return func(x, y) # issue 3
        else:
            return "invalid values" # consider raising an exception here instead!

    return inner # issue 1
```

Comment: Thanks for rectifying the code. I've doubt in the concept of wrapper function. Is it actually necessary to write a nested function to check  whether the values are int or not. I mean can't it be done without using a nested function. For eg:- `def wrapper(x,y): if issubclass(x.__class__, int): return func(x, y) else: return 'invalid values' `

Comment: The nested functions are necessary to make it work as a decorator. Your alternative version could work if you wanted the users of yoru code to call `wrapper` directly, rather than calling `func` by its usual name (though you'd need to name it directly in `wrapper`). Note that your naming of the functions is a bit unusual. Usually the outer function is named for what the purpose of the decorator is (e.g. `arg_type_check` or something) and `wrapper` is the name for the inner function that the decorator returns, "wrapped" around the original function.

Answer (score 0):

## this might work.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args,**kwargs):
        if ((args[0] is int) and (args[1] is int)): pass
        else: return 'invalid values'
    return inner
@wrapper
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
print add('a',2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also raise an exception if you would like to terminate the add method properly if type check fails. like this

```
def check_int_types(func):
    def type_checker(x, y):
        if issubclass(type(x), int) and issubclass(type(y), int):
            return func(x, y)
        raise Exception("Invalid types: {}, {}".format(x, y))
    return type_checker

@check_int_types
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def main():
    x = y = 15.0
    print add(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deco_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "deco_test.py", line 14, in main
    print add(x, y)
  File "deco_test.py", line 5, in type_checker
    raise Exception("Invalid types: {}, {}".format(x, y))
Exception: Invalid types: 15.0, 15.0
```

Answer (score -2):

What about this .

```
def wrapper(func):
    def inner():
        if isinstance(func,int):
                return func(x, y)
        else: return 'invalid values'

    return inner()
```

Comment: It's bad.  That `wrapper` should return a function in order to work as a decorator.  Your solution returns the *result* of a call to `inner`, i. e. you will return the result of a call of `func` or a string (`'invalue values'`).  Neither is a function.