# Can we design any function using a decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

During my interview they asked me a implement a function to reverse each word in a sentence and create final sentence from it. For example:

```
s = 'my life is beautiful'
output - `ym efil si lufituaeb`
```

I know the question is pretty simple so solved it in few minutes:

```
s = 'my life is beautiful'

def reverse_sentence(s):

    string_reverse = []

    for i in s.split():
        string_reverse.append("".join(list((reversed(i)))))

    print " ".join(string_reverse)

reverse_sentence(s)
```

Then they asked to implement the same function using a `decorator`, and I got confused here. I know the basics of `decorator` how it used, and when it used. They didn't mention what part of the function they want to `wrap` using `decorator`. They told me to implement this using `args` and `kwargs`, and I was not able to solve it. Could anyone help me here? How can I convert any function into decorator?

As my per knowledge, you use `decorator` when you want to `wrap your function` or you want to modify the some functionality. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945366/python-decorators)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the task to be performed. How would a decorator even help?

Comment: I guess its not a duplicate!

Comment: Are you sure they didn't say "generator"? There doesn't seem to be any way in which decorators are a natural tool to use here.

Comment: By the way, `s[::-1]` would be a simpler way to reverse the string.

Comment: Here we have to implement the same`functionality (reversing a word)` using `decorator`

Comment: Hey its not a duplicate question. My question is `whether can we convert any function into a decorator` The question interviewer asked seems weird.

Comment: No its not generator @user2357112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def reverse_sentence(fn): # a decorator accepts a function as its argument
    def __inner(s,*args,**kwargs): #it will return this modified function
       string_reverse = []
       for i in s.split():
           string_reverse.append("".join(list((reversed(i)))))          
       return fn(" ".join(string_reverse),*args,**kwargs) 
    return __inner # return the modified function which does your string reverse on its first argument
```

I guess...

```
@reverse_sentence
def printer(s):
    print(s)

printer("hello world")
```

Comment: Why did you use @decorator here?

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct, could you elaborate it little more :)

Comment: Accepting your answer, it seems to be the way they are looking for. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different take -- it defines a decorator which takes a function which sends strings to strings and returns another function which maps the passed function over a split string and then rejoins:

```
def string_map(f): #accepts a function on strings, splits the string, maps the function, then rejoins
    def __f(s,*args,**kwargs):    
       return " ".join(f(t,*args,**kwargs) for t in s.split()) 
    return __f

@string_map
def reverse_string(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

typical output:

```
>>> reverse_string("Hello World")
'olleH dlroW'
```

Comment: Nice, how did you guys master `decorator`? It seems so much work

Comment: I definitely haven't mastered decorators -- but what I do know I have learned from the excellent book "Guide to: Learning Python Decorators" by Matt Harrision. Also -- if you do some reading in functional programming then you realize that decorators are just Python-style higher-order functions.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
# decorator method
def my_decorator(old_func):
    def new_func(*args):
        newargs = (' '.join(''.join(list(args[0])[::-1]).split()[::-1]),)
        old_func(*newargs)  # call the 'real' function

    return new_func  # return the new function object


@my_decorator
def str_rev(mystr):
    print mystr

str_rev('my life is beautiful')
# ym efil si lufituaeb
```