# Can you explain what a decorator is in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm studying Python OOP and I arrived at the topic of decorators but the material I'm using for studying doesn't cover it in depth.
I post the example code:

```
class Duck:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.properties = kwargs

    def quack(self):
        print("Quaaack!")

    def walk(self):
        print("Walk like a duck.")

    def get_properties(self):
        return self.properties

    def get_property(self, key):
        return self.properties.get(key, None)

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self.properties.get("color", None)

    @color.setter
    def color(self, c):
        self.properties["color"] = c

    @color.deleter
    def color(self):
        del self.properties["color"]

def main():
    donald = Duck()
    donald.color = "blue"
    print(donald.color)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Can you help me to understand the importance of decorators?
Can you explain in simple words the concept of decorator?

Comment: There are many articles on decorators on the internet. E.g. http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945366/python-decorators)

Comment: I simply need someone to explain in simple words what a decorator is. (not just comment the code). I don't understand why someone down voted the question. I took a look at a possible duplicate question but in those answers nobody explains in general what a decorator is, so my question is actually unique.

Comment: Check teh second answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python?rq=1
I agree that while fundamentally basic, there is no straight duplicate for this question - at least not one that has popped up in simple searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me write some of the things I can simply say about the above code,

Generally decorators are said to be

> "Function decorators are simply wrappers to existing functions"

Decorators always wrap an another function, Not to mention that the decorator is itself a function

In the above code you are setting,getting,deleting a property/formally  an attribute of a "duck" which is a color.

Decorator always start with the '@'. `@property` is a predefined decorator function that meant to take your getter,setter and del function of your class

```
    @property #getter
    def color(self):
        return self.properties.get("color", None)

    @color.setter #setter
    def color(self, c):
        self.properties["color"] = c

    @color.deleter #del
    def color(self):
        del self.properties["color"]
```

All you have been doing is passing the functions(getter,setter,del) as an argument to the @property

if you written your main it would be like

```
if __name__ == "__main__": main()  
    donald = Duck() //creating object
    donald.color = "blue" //call the setter method, look its more intuitive!!  (you don't using the donald.color("blue") syntax)
    print(donald.color)//getter
```

We can have our own decorator also, I highly recommend you to read the suggested link for its various uses and advantages