# How can i route my URL to a common method before passing to actual view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

Here is my code looks like :-

url.py file :-

```
from rest_framework import routers
from view_user import user_signup,user_login

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^api/v1/user_signup',csrf_exempt(user_signup)),
   url(r'^api/v1/user_login',csrf_exempt(user_login))
]
```

view_user.py file:-

```
def user_signup(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            json_data = json.loads(request.body)
        return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
    except Exception as e:
                logger.error("at method user : %s", e)
```

So, when I call the url:- http://myserver/api/v1/user_signup 
it goes to "user_signup" method of view_user.py file.

But what I want is I should be able validate my request before it goes to the user_signup method.

I want this validation for all the requests that comes to my server for all methods (ex:- user_signup,user_login ...) before it goes to respective methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate the concerned views with a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) that contains the logic you want to execute before the views are called.

See [Python - Decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945366/python-decorators) for a head start.

And [How to write a custom decorator in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469159/how-to-write-a-custom-decorator-in-django)

If you want to do this on all requests, regardless of the associated view, then you should consider writing a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/). See [how to setup custom middleware in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-setup-custom-middleware-in-django)

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion. But decorators I have to add for every method. Is there a way I can validate all request that comes to Django, before I forward to the respective methods.

Comment: @Vinay You should consider writing a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/). See [how to setup custom middleware in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322262/how-to-setup-custom-middleware-in-django)

Comment: Middleware is definitely the answer. One quick note on them. In v 1.10 there is a new style for creating custom Middleware that is not backwards compatible depending upon your settings.py. If you have MIDDLEWARE=(...) then you need a new style.